# Getting Data fom Server into Sqlite DB

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In my application I have a `Sqlite database` locally. When application starts, I am running a `Thread` and getting `Json` data from Server. After parsing these json data, I am creating a `Sqlite` db in my app.
It is in terms long running process and lots of code is written. Everything working fine,

**But, I am just looking if there is another way around to directly populate my local db with this server db? basically a more robust solution.**

Comment: I am also having same scenario, I have created custom classes to hold data and then I am saving in local db

Comment: Try using OrmLite. it'a lightweight framework for ORM in android. and it supports Batch task so it will reduce processing time.

Comment: @SyedZahidAli yeah, and i dont think this is the robust way, as getting row by row is not a good idea, Lots of code and can be break any time.

Comment: @kunalk how will OrmLite handle multi-threading app, having two thread accessing db at same time

Comment: In Ormlite when u are inserting say 1000 records at a time then using callBatchTasks method will perform number of batch tasks. as Ormlite saying this " This is for performance when you want to run a number of database operations at once - maybe loading data from a file. This will turn off what databases call "auto-commit" mode, run the call-able and then re-enable "auto-commit". If auto-commit is not supported then it will try to use a database transaction to speed up the tasks.
  http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_5.html

Comment: @kunalk thanks. i think its OrmLite what I was looking for...

Comment: @SyedZahidAli so you got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OrmLite, kunalk is right. I have tried OrmLite myself, it is fast and easy. By using OrmLite my code is also shirked. OrmLite also have good documentation.